# Parsing local json file on Swift

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, parsing

I have a local JSON and try to decode but got "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead" error. The json file and two structs below:

```
 {
"Stanford University": [{
        "type": "government",
        "name": "Stanford University",
        "city": "Santa Clara",
        "major": "Computer Engineering"
    },
    {
        "type": "government",
        "name": "Stanford University",
        "city": "Santa Clara",
        "major": "Economics"
    }
],
"Berkeley University": [{
        "type": "foundation",
        "name": "Berkeley University",
        "city": "Alameda",
        "major": "Communication"
    },
    {
        "type": "foundation",
        "name": "Berkeley University",
        "city": "Alameda",
        "major": "Physics"
    }
]
```

}

two structs:

```
struct Universite4: Codable {  
    let name: String?
    let major:[Major]?
} 

struct Major: Codable {
    let type: String?
    let name: String?
    let major: String? }
```

And this is code for data load and decode;

```
public class DataLoader {
    
    @Published var universite4 = [Universite4]()
    
    init() {
        load()
    }
    
    func load() {
        if let unv4json = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "unv4", withExtension: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: unv4json)
                let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                let dataFromJson = try jsonDecoder.decode([Universite4].self, from:data)
                
                
                self.universite4 = dataFromJson
                
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how can I fix above code? Regards.

Comment: Easiest is to use the site https://quicktype.io that can convert your json into swift structs. But basically the error is pretty clear, you are trying to decode the json data as an array but it is a dictionary with “Stanford University” as key. (And the struct Major is not relevant)

Comment: Sorry Joakim, it ws my mistake, I have fix the json and past again. The struct Major is now relevant.

Comment: Well you don't have a key "name" at the top level in the json so now is Universite4 not relevant, see the answer below from Camilo

Comment: Hi Joakim, what if I don't have "name" key at the top level of json? It can be implemented by some other ways?

Comment: Again, look at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change, the issue here is that actually your keys are sort of "Dynamic keys" which I don't recommend but if you have to use them, so try this.

```swift
let dataFromJson = try jsonDecoder.decode([Universite4].self, from:data)
```

to

```swift
let dataFromJson = try jsonDecoder.decode([String:[Major]].self, from:data)
```